# How can i make usage to print only once

Tags: shell-script

```
#!/bin/bash

usage ()

 {

echo "run with 1st argument

       -mux2 or mux4 or mux8 or default(mux2) or all ( all the 3 mux)" 

echo "2nd argument 

      -struct or ifs or cases or asgn or default(struct) or all(all the 

       conditions)"

echo "3rd argument 

    -on (waveform) or off (no wave) or default(off)'
echo "run 

      - should take mux2 struct off as arguments"
}

if [ "$1" == "mux2" -o "$1" == "mux4" -o "$1" == "mux8" ]; then

if [ "$2" == "struct" -o "$2" == "ifs" -o "$2" == "cases" -o "$2"=="asgn" ]; then

  if [ "$3" == "on" ]; then

  iverilog -o mux "$1".v  "$1"TB.v -D "$2" 

  vvp mux

  gtkwave T.vcd

  elif [ "$3" == "off" -o "$3" == "" ]; then

  iverilog -o mux "$1".v  "$1"TB.v -D "$2" 

  vvp mux

  else

  usage

  fi

 elif [ "$2" == "all" ]; then

 $0 $1 struct $3

 $0 $1 ifs $3

 $0 $1 cases $3

 $0 $1 asgn $3

 elif [ "$2" =="" ]; then

 $0 $2 struct $3

 else

 usage

 fi

elif [ "$1" == "all" ]; then

$0 mux2 $2 $3

$0 mux4 $2 $3

$0 mux8 $2 $3

elif [ "$1" == "" ]; then

$0 mux2 stuct

else

usage

fi
```

The usage is displaying more than once when I run script with the following arguments:

```
run all jhjjk
run all all kjkj
```

How can I make usage to print only once?

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo after `default(off)`, where you have `'` instead of `"`. Apart from that it works fine for me. I commented out most of the commands, and put in `echo`s to debug. Creating a minimal example is often useful. With this, using `all` as the first argument worked fine. Here is your original script with the `"` fix and with better indenting, which makes debugging much easier.

```
#!/bin/bash

usage ()
 {
echo "run with 1st argument
  -mux2 or mux4 or mux8 or default(mux2) or all ( all the 3 mux)" 
echo "2nd argument 
  -struct or ifs or cases or asgn or default(struct) or all(all the conditions)"
echo "3rd argument
  -on (waveform) or off (no wave) or default(off)"
echo "run 
  - should take mux2 struct off as arguments"
}

if [ "$1" == "mux2" -o "$1" == "mux4" -o "$1" == "mux8" ]; then
  if [ "$2" == "struct" -o "$2" == "ifs" -o "$2" == "cases" -o "$2"=="asgn" ]; then
    if [ "$3" == "on" ]; then
      iverilog -o mux "$1".v  "$1"TB.v -D "$2" 
      vvp mux
      gtkwave T.vcd
    elif [ "$3" == "off" -o "$3" == "" ]; then
      iverilog -o mux "$1".v  "$1"TB.v -D "$2" 
      vvp mux
    else
      usage
    fi
  elif [ "$2" == "all" ]; then
    $0 $1 struct $3
    $0 $1 ifs $3
    $0 $1 cases $3
    $0 $1 asgn $3
  elif [ "$2" =="" ]; then
    $0 $2 struct $3
  else
    usage
  fi
elif [ "$1" == "all" ]; then
  $0 mux2 $2 $3
  $0 mux4 $2 $3
  $0 mux8 $2 $3
elif [ "$1" == "" ]; then
  $0 mux2 stuct
else
  usage
fi
```

And here is a version that I used that works fine.

```
#!/bin/bash

usage ()
 {
echo "run with 1st argument
  -mux2 or mux4 or mux8 or default(mux2) or all ( all the 3 mux)" 
echo "2nd argument 
  -struct or ifs or cases or asgn or default(struct) or all(all the conditions)"
echo "3rd argument
  -on (waveform) or off (no wave) or default(off)"
echo "run 
  - should take mux2 struct off as arguments"
}

if [ "$1" == "mux2" -o "$1" == "mux4" -o "$1" == "mux8" ]; then
  if [ "$2" == "struct" -o "$2" == "ifs" -o "$2" == "cases" -o "$2"=="asgn" ]; then
    if [ "$3" == "on" ]; then
#      iverilog -o mux "$1".v  "$1"TB.v -D "$2" 
#      vvp mux
#      gtkwave T.vcd
echo 1
    elif [ "$3" == "off" -o "$3" == "" ]; then
#      iverilog -o mux "$1".v  "$1"TB.v -D "$2" 
#      vvp mux
echo 2
    else
      usage
    fi
  elif [ "$2" == "all" ]; then
#    $0 $1 struct $3
#    $0 $1 ifs $3
#    $0 $1 cases $3
#    $0 $1 asgn $3
echo 3
  elif [ "$2" =="" ]; then
#    $0 $2 struct $3
echo 4
  else
    usage
  fi
elif [ "$1" == "all" ]; then
#  $0 mux2 $2 $3
#  $0 mux4 $2 $3
#  $0 mux8 $2 $3
echo 5
elif [ "$1" == "" ]; then
#  $0 mux2 stuct
echo 6
else
  usage
fi
```

`run all jhjjk` and `run all all kjkj` both return `5` as expected.

---

### EDIT

The simplest way to get out of recursive hell as created by

```
$0 mux2 $2 $3
$0 mux4 $2 $3
$0 mux8 $2 $3
```

is to make each groups of commands a subroutine. Then, use the branching structure to call these subroutine, or print out the usage if it's nonsense. IMO recursion is just too messy for this task.

Comment: You said "The usage is displaying more than once…". When I tested it with the script above, it didn't display at all. You've written your script so that when `$1 == all`, then it enters the branch I've marked with `echo 5`. I don't quite understand what you want.

Comment: @Sparhawkwhat are these echo1,echo2 echo3i need to execute those commands.

Comment: As stated in the answer, I was creating a minimal example to debug. Also, I don't have `vvp`, `iverilog`, etc. on my system (nor do I know what those commands do).

Comment: @Sparhawk..yeah it ll enter echo 5 for $1== all and it will  check for $2 and displays usage when $2 is invalid....usage is displaying 3 times as it will be executed for mux2,mux4 and mux8.i want to display usage only once

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying. So now you are saying that it's displaying usage 3 times, not 2? And you are suggesting that the three lines beginning with `$0 mux2 $2 $3` are responsible for this?

Comment: You didn't answer my other questions.

Comment: yeah you are right ...those 3 lines are responsible .i want to display usage once.usage will be printed many times when i give `$1==all ,`$2==all` and $3 is invalid.commands in echo 3 and echo 5 are responsiblefor this

Comment: can i use count here..usage should be executed only when `count== "0"` and incrementing count after every usage

Comment: Ah okay, I understand… it's recursively calling itself. I still don't totally get it, because `run all jhjjk` goes to the branch which I've marked `echo 2`, not the `usage` one. Anyway, something like `count` would work, although a boolean, is probably more correct. Also, you'd have to pass this variable as an argument of the next call. Honestly, the simplest way by far is to define subroutines for the actual commands. Use the branching structure to then call these subroutines. Then you won't even need to call the command again, and all your variables are contained in one script.

Comment: nope it will go to the branch which you have marked echo 5 as `$1==all` and then to usage as $2 is invalid.i am trying to display usage whenever i give wrong $1 ,$2 and $3

Comment: Okay, but what about refactoring with subroutines?

Comment: @ Sparhawk i am weak in writing subroutines and calling them.its very difficult for me to write as it has many arguments and am very new to shell scrip but i will try

Comment: @user3331420 You really shouldn't fear them! Have a read of a short [tutorial](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-8.html). It really is that simple! It will make your script so much easier to read and debug.

Answer (score 0):

To parse parameters and options in your script, I would use [getopts](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/getopts_tutorial). It offers the functionality you search.

But anymway, to make your script run, add `exit` after this line:

```
echo "run 

      - should take mux2 struct off as arguments"
exit
}
```

Comment: nope its not working .its displaying usage more than once when $1=all and $2=kkj(invalid argument)

Comment: The script is recursive, and called more than once.
Each instance will display once.
This solution would work when you convert the recursive solution into a function, as @Sparhawk suggested.

Comment: @WalterA code will be too long if i use functions instead of recursive solution

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using a function, but when you must use a recursive solution:

```
#!/bin/bash  
usage()
{
         echo Usage without recursive check
         if [ "${USAGE_PRINTED}" = "notyet" ]; then
                 echo Usage xxxx
                 export USAGE_PRINTED="Yes the operator already understands it"
         else
                 echo "ok"

         fi
}

if [ -z "${USAGE_PRINTED}" ]; then
         export USAGE_PRINTED="notyet"
fi

if [ $# -gt 1 ]; then
         echo Parameters $*
         usage
         shift
         $0 $*
else
         echo Parameters $*
         usage
fi
```

Output when you run this program with parameters 1 2 3 4:

```
Parameters 1 2 3 4
Usage without recursive check
Usage xxxx
Parameters 2 3 4
Usage without recursive check
ok
Parameters 3 4
Usage without recursive check
ok
Parameters 4
Usage without recursive check
ok
```

The lines with "Usage without recursive check" demonstrates the problem,
Shifting parameters is done for ending the recursive calls after a few steps.
The echo "ok" can be deleted.

Comment: i didn't get you.tried  by adding above lines in usage but its not working